# How can I subclass a model and save the additional data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my app, it makes sense (to me) to subclass users, which I have done like so:

```
public class User
{
    public string eRaiderUsername { get; set; }
    public int AllowedSpaces { get; set; }
    public ContactInformation ContactInformation { get; set; }
    public Ethnicity Ethnicity { get; set; }
    public Classification Classification { get; set; }
    public Living Living { get; set; }
}

public class Student : User
{
    public Student()
    {
        AllowedSpaces = AppSettings.AllowedStudentSpaces;
    }
}

public class OrganizationRepresentative : User
{
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public OrganizationRepresentative()
    {
        AllowedSpaces = AppSettings.AllowedOrganizationSpaces;
    }
}
```

The only relationship that would store a `User` (or `Student` or `OrganizationRepresentative`) id will happen with the reservation model:

```
public class Reservation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SpaceNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public Reservation() { }
}
```

Here is the current context:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("ApplicationConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

I haven't actually started saving `Users` in my database or attempted to connect a `Reservation` to a `User` (yet).

**When dealing with user subclasses (`Student` and `OrganizationRepresentative`), should the application store each user subclass seperately? How would I create a relationship between Reservations and Users, and how would I setup the Database Context for `Users` or for `Students` and `OrganizationRepresentatives` (depending on the approach)?**

Comment: Listen to Greg Young. I think, he can help you solve your issue http://vimeo.com/31645099. Other than that, your question is too broad

Comment: Check out this blog post: http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/10/mixing-inheritance-strategies-in-entity.html it describes the different inheritance methods and gives some information on why one should be chosen over another

Answer (score 2):

As OO programmers, it is very easy to fall in to the trap of deriving classes from one another to begin "specialisation", and start defining "roles".  This sort of falls down very quickly when multiple roles are introduced, or when an employee buys a car from the company he works from and becomes both an employee and a client.  What to do?

The answer is to separate roles from the people doing them.  Whether you do this using flags, or a many-to-many table which links people to "roles", "purposes", or whatever you want to call it, is up to you.

Inheritance in a role-based scenario pretty much always ends up in tears when you try and retro-fit things.  Spend the time *now* to fix it.

Comment: I believe that with proper care, subclassing of a user object can make sense; with the caveat that the objects should not represent roles (has-a) but should be fundamental types. If you start with a `Party` class, and subclass this with `Organization` and `Person`, that's actually a solution to avoid the issue that you're pointing out (whoops, an Employee can also be a Customer). See [A Universal Person and Organization Data Model
](http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5014/). Creating an `Employee` class and a `User` class without inheritance (of a base `Person`) could lead to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

ef Copes with the various possibilities.

[Table per Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618293)

[Table per Hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292)

Have a play around saving and retrieving data to see how it works and what suits best.
Use OO the way the works best for you